# nested async methods and thread pool Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm building an `async` Web Api and after reading some articles about `async`/`await` I think I'm doing something wrong.

this is my actual code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccount(int id)
{
    var i = await GetInstanceIdAsync(User, _db); //grabs a thread
    ...
}

public async static Task<int> GetInstanceIdAsync(IPrincipal user, Entities db)
{
    var userManager = 
         new UserManager<ControliUser>(new UserStore<ControliUser>(db));
    //next line grabs another thread but since it was called from an await
    //it holds 2 threads, am I correct?
    var u = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.Identity.Name);
    return u == null ? 0 : u.InstanceId ?? 0;
}
```

**So my first question is, Is this consuming 2 threads?**

If the answer is yes, then I made this extension method to prevent that.

```
public static Task<int?> InstanceIdAsync(this Entities db, IPrincipal user)
{
    var userManager = new UserManager<ControliUser>(new UserStore<ControliUser>(db));
    return userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.Identity.Name).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsCompleted && t.Result != null)
            return t.Result.InstanceId;
        return null;
    });
}
```

I think this method will only consume 1 thread and reduce overhead since it saves an `async` method

**Am I correct?**

Comment: Oldie but goodie - [Asynchronous Programming in C# 5.0 part two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx) by Eric Lippert - "The whole point of async methods it that you stay on the current thread as much as possible"

Comment: await mostly is a fancy way to say ContinueWith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my first question is, Is this consuming 2 threads?

No. Using *async-await* doesn't generate any extra thread use. On the contrary, it frees the thread while the async operation is ongoing. This means that the thread will be used until the call to `FindByNameAsync`, then it will be freed, only to resume once that operation is complete. Then, it will resume the operation (code after the first `await`) on an arbitrary thread-pool thread, while preserving the request context.

> I think this method will only consume 1 thread and reduce overhead
>   since it saves an async method

First of all, this won't work in WebAPI. The problem is that the continuation will only execute once the first task completes. This in turn, will signal the synchronization context that there are on-finished IO operations on-going, and will cause an exception.

As previously said, the async method doesn't generate any thread-use, all it does is create a ***state-machine*** so it can invoke the continuation of your method (any calls after the first `await`) properly.